# remove child entity when re-attach the parent entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, persistence

I have a situation at which the user can remove child entity from a list:

```
@Entity
public class StandaredPriceTag {
.
.
.
@OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, fetch = FetchType.EAGER,mappedBy="standaredPriceTag")
List<StandaredPrice> standaredPriceList = new ArrayList<>();
```

and

```
@Entity
public class StandaredPrice {
    .
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "standard_price_tag_id")
    private StandaredPriceTag standaredPriceTag;
    .
```

As I understand as long as the `StandaredPriceTag` is attached to the entity manager any update will be reflected into the DB. Now, when I remove an item from `List<StandaredPrice> standaredPriceList` and then re-attach `StandaredPriceTag` as `entityManager.merge(standaredPriceTag);`, the child entity still exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to go step further as set-up the orphan removal on the `@OneToMany`. With standard `CascadeType.DELETE`, you need to explicitly remove the entity. With the orphan removal you just need to clear it from the list as you did:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }
  , fetch = FetchType.EAGER,mappedBy="standaredPriceTag"
  , orphanRemoval = true)
List<StandaredPrice> standaredPriceList = new ArrayList<>();
```